# Invalid character in my array of a function...Code Check

Tags: errors, characters

I'm getting an invalid character error from the following array that I'm entering in my document. I don't see any characters that could be invalid:

```
\begin{equation*}
f(\textbf{x}) = \left[\begin{array}
                    f_{1}(\mathbf{x}) \\
                    \vdots \\
                    f_{n}(\mathbf{x})
                    \end{array} \right]
\end{equation*}
```

Perhaps a new set of eyes could see what is wrong. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Perhaps is the combination of `textbf{}` and `\mathbf{}`, although I haven't tested.

Comment: that combo worked elsewhere, but I'll give it a try. EDIT: changing it to `mathbf}` didn't help unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it, you have to add the justification option `{c}` to the array environment. This works for me:

```
\begin{equation*}
f(\textbf{x}) = \left[\begin{array}{c}
                    f_{1}(\mathbf{x}) \\
                    \vdots \\
                    f_{n}(\mathbf{x})
                    \end{array} \right]
\end{equation*}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I think that makes sense...Tired it and it works. Thanks.